# Getting extended properties with other properties

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network

I have a PS script that collects information for all Az Virtual Network gateways but there seems to be an issue getting name of the resource. I am getting Name with red arrow in a screenshot instead of Name with Yellow arrow.

[image]

```
$gatewayDetailsArray = @()

# Loop through each subscription
#foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
 #   Write-Host "Processing Subscription: $($subscription.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # Select the current subscription
  #   Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # Get all resource groups in the current subscription
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

    # Loop through each resource group to get virtual network gateways
    foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
       # $gateways = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName  | Select-Object -Property Name, GatewayType, VpnType, Sku -ExpandProperty IpConfigurations

        
       # Loop through each virtual network gateway and add details to the array
        foreach ($gateway in $gateways) {
            $details = @{
                Subscription = $subscription.Name
                ResourceGroupName = $gateway.ResourceGroupName
                Name = $gateway.Name
                GatewayType = $gateway.GatewayType
                VpnType = $gateway.VpnType
                GatewayIP = $gateway.GatewayIpAddress
                SKU = $gateway.Sku.Name
                VNET = ($gateway.subnet.id -split '/')[-3]
            }
            $gatewayDetailsArray += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        }
    }
#}

# Export the gateway details array to a CSV file
$csvFilePath2 = "C:\temp\GatewayDetails_2.csv"
$gatewayDetailsArray | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath2 -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To collect information of all Virtual Network gateways in your subscription, you can make use of the below modified script:

```c
# $subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Initialize an array to store gateway details
$gatewayDetailsArray = @()

# Loop through each subscription
#foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
 #   Write-Host "Processing Subscription: $($subscription.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # Select the current subscription
  #   Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # <span class=" active-doc-0" data-doc-items="0">Get all resource groups in the current subscription[1](#doc-pos=0)</span>
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

    # Loop through each resource group to get virtual network gateways
    foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
        $gateways = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

        
       # <span class=" active-doc-1" data-doc-items="1">Loop through each virtual network gateway and add details to the array[2](#doc-pos=1)</span>
        foreach ($gateway in $gateways) {
            $details = @{
                Subscription = $subscription.Name
                ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
                Name = $gateway
            }
            $gatewayDetailsArray += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        }
    }
#}

# Output the gateway details
$gatewayDetailsArray | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Export the gateway details array to a CSV file
$csvFilePath2 = "C:\temp\GatewayDetails_2.csv"
$gatewayDetailsArray | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath2 -NoTypeInformation
```

***Output***:

[image]

In csv, file got exported like below:

[image]

---

```
# $subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Initialize an array to store gateway details
$gatewayDetailsArray = @()

# Loop through each subscription
#foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
 #   Write-Host "Processing Subscription: $($subscription.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # Select the current subscription
  #   Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # <span class=" active-doc-0" data-doc-items="0">Get all resource groups in the current subscription[1](#doc-pos=0)</span>
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

    # Loop through each resource group to get virtual network gateways
    foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
        $gateways = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

        
       # <span class=" active-doc-1" data-doc-items="1">Loop through each virtual network gateway and add details to the array[2](#doc-pos=1)</span>
        foreach ($gateway in $gateways) {
            $details = @{
                Subscription = $subscription.Name
                ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
                Name = $gateway
                vpnType = $gateway.VpnType
                GatewayType = $gateway.GatewayType
                SKU = $gateway.Sku.Name
                VNET = ($gateway.subnet.id -split '/')[-3]
            }
            $gatewayDetailsArray += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        }
    }
#}

# Output the gateway details
$gatewayDetailsArray | Format-Table -AutoSize


$csvFilePath2 = "C:\temp\GatewayDetails_2.csv"
$gatewayDetailsArray | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath2 -NoTypeInformation
```

### Update

> We would like below in output. Gatway name, Subscription ID, Resource group, VPNType, SKU name, Subnet ID from IPconfigurations (refer to original screenshot) so that we can extract VNET detail

You can make use of below command to get all the details like below:

```
# Initialize an array to store gateway details
$gatewayDetailsArray = @()

# Get all subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Loop through each subscription
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    Write-Host "Processing Subscription: $($subscription.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # Select the current subscription
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # Get all resource groups in the current subscription
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

    # Loop through each resource group to get virtual network gateways
    foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
        $gateways = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName | Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name="SubscriptionID";Expression={$subscription.Id}}, ResourceGroupName, VpnType, @{Name="SKUName";Expression={$_.Sku.Name}}, @{Name="SubnetID";Expression={$_.IpConfigurations.Subnet.Id}}, @{Name="SubnetName";Expression={(Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -ResourceId $_.IpConfigurations.Subnet.Id).Name}}

        # Loop through each virtual network gateway and add details to the array
        foreach ($gateway in $gateways) {
            $gatewayDetailsArray += $gateway
        }
    }
}

# Output the gateway details
$gatewayDetailsArray | Format-Table -AutoSize Name, SubscriptionID, ResourceGroupName, VpnType, SKUName, SubnetID, SubnetName

# Export the gateway details array to a CSV file
$csvFilePath2 = "C:\temp\GatewayDetails_2.csv"
$gatewayDetailsArray | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath2 -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No this doesn't meet our requirements. We have more than 1000 subscriptions and we need to build a PowerBI report to keep track of resources. The existing script I posted above contains VNET the gateway is associated with that we can use to match other resouces. I wanted to know if we can get Name of gateway in that script or in other way where we can also get extended properties. A simple export of gateways will not be useful as we want these to related with VNET associated to them.

Comment: Does this fulfill your requirement? Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/WbNx6c0.png) it displays all the subscriptions and provide vpn gateway details. In my case I have vpn gateway in 1 subscription only.

Comment: The issue here is that I am getting other information like SKUname, VPNtype, SubnetID. I modified the script to include these values in output but there are coming up blank. I am Copying modified script below.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what values exactly you needed?

Comment: We would like below in output.
Gatway name, 
Subscription ID, 
Resource group, 
VPNType, 
SKU name, 
Subnet ID from IPconfigurations (refer to original screenshot) so that we can extract VNET details